# Arraydeque intermixed operations

Tags: java

I want to ask what is the behavior of Arraydeque when add operation, then push. And removing the items. 
Does the queue remove elements from the head  or the tail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `java.util.ArrayDeque.add(E e)` method inserts the specified element E at the **end** of the deque.

The `java.util.ArrayDeque.remove(E e)` method will remove from the **front** of the deque.

The `java.util.ArrayDeque.push(E e)` adds an element to the **front** (or the top) of the ArrayDeque.

The `java.util.ArrayDeque.pop(E e)` removes the **topmost** element of the ArrayDeque and returns it. Pop() throws an exception if empty.

Comment: I know that. My scenario is add, push then remove or pop